# No provider for HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript

After upgrading from angular 4.4 to 5.0 and after updating all HttpModule and Http to HttpClientModule I started to get this error.

I also added HttpModule again to be sure it's not due to some dependency but it doesn't resolve the issue

In app.module, I have all correctly set

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
.
.
.
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
.
.
.
```

I don't know from where this error is coming, or I have no clue how to get inner of it. I also have a warning (put it below too) maybe its related.

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at _NullInjector.get (vendor.js?v=mekBM8IVBK72-MIZOVSTJizGi_TD_xK3uhPOCRlEHwg:5665)
    at resolveToken (vendor.js?v=mekBM8IVBK72-MIZOVSTJizGi_TD_xK3uhPOCRlEHwg:5953)
    at tryResolveToken (vendor.js?v=mekBM8IVBK72-MIZOVSTJizGi_TD_xK3uhPOCRlEHwg:5895)
    at StaticInjector.get (vendor.js?v=mekBM8IVBK72-MIZOVSTJizGi_TD_xK3uhPOCRlEHwg:5766)
    at resolveToken (vendor.js?v=mekBM8IVBK72-MIZOVSTJizGi_TD_xK3uhPOCRlEHwg:5953)
    at tryResolveToken (vendor.js?v=mekBM8IVBK72-MIZOVSTJizGi_TD_xK3uhPOCRlEHwg:5895)
    at StaticInjector.get (vendor.js?v=mekBM8IVBK72-MIZOVSTJizGi_TD_xK3uhPOCRlEHwg:5766)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.js?v=mekBM8IVBK72-MIZOVSTJizGi_TD_xK3uhPOCRlEHwg:15328)
    at _createClass (vendor.js?v=mekBM8IVBK72-MIZOVSTJizGi_TD_xK3uhPOCRlEHwg:15373)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (vendor.js?v=mekBM8IVBK72-MIZOVSTJizGi_TD_xK3uhPOCRlEHwg:15339)
```

Warning Message:

```
./node_modules/@angular/Common/esm5/http.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* D:\XXX\node_modules\@angular\Common\esm5\http.js
    Used by 21 module(s), i. e.
    D:\XXX\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\dist\entry.js?silent=true!D:\XXX\node_modules\angular2-template-loader\index.js!D:\XXX\ClientApp\app\services\notification-endpoint.service.ts
* D:\XXX\node_modules\@angular\common\esm5\http.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    D:\XXX\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\dist\entry.js?silent=true!D:\XXX\node_modules\angular2-template-loader\index.js!D:\XXX\ClientApp\app\app.module.ts
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/Common/esm5/http.js
 @ ./ClientApp/app/services/notification-endpoint.service.ts
 @ ./ClientApp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
 @ multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
```

### Current behavior

`StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!`

### Environment

```
Angular version: 5.0.0 and 5.0.1 (also 5.1 beta)

Browser:
- all

For Tooling issues:
- Node version: 8.5.0
- Platform:  windows
```

```json
{
  "name": "X",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "X",
  "author": {
    "name": "X X",
    "email": "XX",
    "url": "X"
  },
  "homepage": "X",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0-beta.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.4",
    "bootstrap-toggle": "^2.2.2",
    "bootstrap-vertical-tabs": "^1.2.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.11",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "node-sass": "^4.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.6",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.20.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.6.3",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev-build": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js",
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] },
                { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize', 'sass-loader'] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new AotPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module#AppModule')
                })
            ])
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig];
};
```

webpack.config.vendor.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'core-js/client/shim',
    'web-animations-js',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
    '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css',
    'ng2-toasty',
    'ng2-toasty/bundles/style-bootstrap.css',
    'ng2-charts',
    'ngx-bootstrap/modal',
    'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip',
    'ngx-bootstrap/popover',
    'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown',
    'ngx-bootstrap/carousel',
    'bootstrap-vertical-tabs/bootstrap.vertical-tabs.css',
    'bootstrap-toggle/css/bootstrap-toggle.css',
    'bootstrap-toggle/js/bootstrap-toggle.js',
    'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css',
    'bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js',
    'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css',
    'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js'] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(gif|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
            // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig];
}
```

Comment: are you using angular2-jwt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129865/7018464

Comment: is this an angular-cli project? could you please add your package.json

Comment: No, its a .core 2.0 project and it was working till angular 5 and httpclientmodule upgrade. And below link is also same with above answer but it doesnt helps because httpclient is already in constructors where its used.

Comment: Hi Jota,project.json added

Comment: Any chance to see a minimal reproduction?

Comment: this is a very big project i dont know how can i shrink it to a smaller version to show the version, it would be very hard i think

Comment: Can you add your webpack.config.vendor.js?

Comment: webpack.config and webpack.config.vendor files added

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 Error: No provider for HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569404/angular-4-error-no-provider-for-httpclient)

Comment: No its not a duplicate they are different and its answer is already correct at my side and same problem happens even i have a test file and without a test file

Comment: for me .. i resolved it by add HttpClientModule to imports and provider array

Comment: Just in case this helps someone else: you will also get this error if you forget the `@Injectable()` class decorator on the interceptor. Just spent a while scratching my head trying to figure out what was wrong..

Answer (score 1304):

To resolve this problem `HttpClient` is Angular's mechanism for communicating with a remote server over HTTP.

To make `HttpClient` available everywhere in the app,

1. open the root `AppModule`,
2. import the `HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http`,

   `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`
3. add it to the `@NgModule.imports` array.

   `imports:[HttpClientModule,  ]`

Comment: This fixed it for me. I had put mine in the declarations by accident.

Comment: Import it only in the app.module, and nowhere else, not in sub modules

Comment: Too bad that the OP has not taken a second to accept this as the answer...

Comment: I am happy to announce this solution is covered by Assistant https://medium.com/@tomaszs2/mapping-stackoverflow-into-real-time-assistance-e627dda88f69

Comment: Do you not also need to add HttpClientModule to @NgModule.providers?

Comment: Unfortunately fix not working in angular 10

Comment: I do this but this error stills,  then I added HttpClientModule in te providers arrary in app.module.ts, then save  and run fine then I delete HttpClientModule of providers arrays and run fine

Answer (score 229):

You have not provided providers in your module:

```js
<strike>import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';</strike>
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [ HttpClientModule, ... ]
  // ...
})
export class MyModule { /* ... */ }
```

### Using HttpClient in Tests

You will need to add the `HttpClientTestingModule` to the TestBed configuration when running `ng test` and getting the "No provider for HttpClient" error:

```js
// Http testing module and mocking controller
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

// Other imports
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('HttpClient testing', () => {
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ]
    });

    // Inject the http service and test controller for each test
    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('works', () => {
  });
});
```

Comment: no, this isnt documented that httpclientmodule should be added to providers list. But anyways, i tried your answer too to be sure but as expected the same error continues after adding it to providers list.

Comment: I guess "HttpClientModule" should be added to imports, not providers

Comment: I had to add `imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]` to my `TestBed.configureTestingModule` to get rid of this error **in tests**.

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy comment was the answer to my problem with this in Jasmine.

Comment: import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

Comment: @HimmetYelekin - Here's the official document from Angular. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: Yaroslav's comment saved me too, over a year later (failing tests using Jest)

Comment: I'm new to Angular so I don't understand the internals well enough. But given the error in the console says that no provider for HttpClientModule. I added it to the providers list of the sub-module that implements the service that requires the dependency injection. It was of course still listed in imports as well. That definitely fixed it. I'm not sure if all things being dependency injected are required to be a provider. Maybe it varies by Angular version. I'm running 9.1.9, typescript 3.8.3 and Node 12.18.0.

Comment: "from v9.0.0 use TestBed.inject" instead of Testbed.get

Comment: I have to import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts` it fixed my error.

Answer (score 68):

You are getting error for HttpClient so, you are missing HttpClientModule for that.

You should import it in app.module.ts file like this -

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and mention it in the NgModule Decorator like this -

```js
@NgModule({
...
imports:[ HttpClientModule ]
...
})
```

If this even doesn't work try clearing cookies of the browser and try restarting your server. Hopefully it may work, I was getting the same error.

Comment: Adding HttpClientModule to imports solved the issue, because its value was not used, Thanks @Vivek kushwaha

Answer (score 47):

Just Add `HttpClientModule` in 'imports' array of `app.module.ts` file.

```
...
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'; // add this line
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule, //add this line
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and then you can use `HttpClient` in your project through constructor injection

```
  import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
  
  export class Services{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

Comment: Have spent a while scratching my head trying to figure out what went wrong. This solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 36):

I had same issue. After browsing and struggling with issue found the below solution

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

imports: [
  HttpModule,
  HttpClientModule
]
```

Import `HttpModule` and `HttpClientModule` in app.module.ts and add into the imports like mentioned above.

Comment: using the HttpModule (deprecated) and the HttpClientModule (replaces HttpModule) makes no sense

Comment: Yes. Just import HttpClientModule.

Answer (score 32):

*step 1*: import the `HttpClientModule` in **app.module.ts**:

```js
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

*step 2*: inside the module imports add `HttpClientModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ....
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 31):

I was also facing similar issue by doing below changes, it worked for me

In app.modules.ts

```js
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
```

and in corresponding service class

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
```

constructor should look like as below

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private xyz: xyzService) {}
```

In test file

```js
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing'

  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
  }));
```

Comment: Importing HttpClientModule on app.module.ts is not enough to resolve the problem, but I upvote you anyway for reminding me what I missed.

Comment: Importing HttpClientTestingModule solved the problem in specs

Answer (score 26):

With the recent changes in angular there is no **app.module** file.  So with the new structure you will have to upate it in **app.config** file and add

**provideHttpClient()**

```js
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { provideRouter, withHashLocation } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes, withHashLocation()),
    provideHttpClient()
  ]
};
```

or if you want to add auth interceptor then you can do it like

```js
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideHttpClient, withInterceptors } from '@angular/common/http'
import { provideRouter, withHashLocation } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes, withHashLocation()),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([authenticationInterceptor]))
  ]
};
```

interceptor can be declared like

```js
import { HttpHandlerFn, HttpInterceptorFn, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";

export const authenticationInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next:
    HttpHandlerFn) => {
    const modifiedReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`),
    });

    return next(modifiedReq);
};
```

Comment: This worked for me with Angular 17. `provideHttpClient` is imported via `import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: it is working for me also in Angular 17

Comment: Worked for me with Angular 17. Thank you.

Comment: @YogeshJog please add the resource docs

Answer (score 22):

Go to `app.module.ts`

import `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

AND

Add `HttpClientModule` under imports

should look like this

```
imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,HttpClientModule]
```

Answer (score 22):

The issue is more due to not registering the required services i.e `HttpClientModule` in the root module ie. `NgModule`.

You are missing `HttpClientModule` since you are receiving an error for `HttpClient`

You should import it in the `app.module.ts` file as follows,

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and mention it in the `NgModule` Decorator like this -

```
@NgModule({
...
imports:[ HttpClientModule ]
...
})
```

Hopefully, it may work.
See the below image to getting more idea.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

I was facing the same issue, the funny thing was I had two projects opened on simultaneously, I have changed the wrong app.modules.ts files.

First, check that.

After that change add the following code to the **app.module.ts** file

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

After that add the following to the imports array in the **app.module.ts** file

```js
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,....
  ],
```

Now you should be ok!

Answer (score 14):

I was facing the same problem, then in my **app.module.ts** I updated the file this way,

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and in the same file **(app.module.ts)** in my *@NgModule* imports[]array I wrote this way,

```js
HttpModule,
HttpClientModule
```

Answer (score 12):

I got this error after injecting a Service which used HTTPClient into a class. The class was again used in the service, so it created a circular dependency. I could compile the app with warnings, but in browser console the error occurred

"No provider for HttpClient! (MyService -> HttpClient)"

and it broke the app.

This works:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyClass } from "../classes/my.class";

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ){
    // do something with myClass Instances
  }      
}
.
.
.
export class MenuItem {
  constructor(

  ){}
}
```

This breaks the app

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MyClass } from "../classes/my.class";

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ){
    // do something with myClass Instances
  }      
}
.
.
.
import { MyService } from '../services/my.service';
export class MyClass {
  constructor(
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([MyService]);
    this.myService = injector.get(MyService);
  ){}
}
```

After injecting MyService in MyClass I got the circular dependency warning. CLI compiled anyway with this warning but the app did not work anymore and the error was given in browser console. So in my case it didn't had to do anything with @NgModule but with circular dependencies. I recommend to solve the case sensitive naming warnings if your problem still exist.

Answer (score 11):

Fixed by adding **`HttpClientModule`** provider in **`imports`** section

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ]
})
```

This we need to add in **`src -> app -> app.module.ts`** file.

Answer (score 10):

I found slimier problem. Please import the HttpClientModule in your app.module.ts file as follow:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
],

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 10):

Under app.module.ts -> import section, you need to add HttpClientModule. Below is the sample

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,  // This is where you need to add
        FormsModule,
    ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Add `HttpModule` and `HttpClientModule` in both imports and providers in app.module.ts solved the issue.
**imports** -> `import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";`

Comment: I have the same problema. I looked in App_modules and I do not have http directory in path @angular-->common I run "npm update" I am working with Windows 8.i, nodejs versión 9.7.1. I am Reading Valerio de Sanctis book... what can it be? Thanks

Comment: just run 'npm i' with administrator mode.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem. For me the fix was to import HttpModule before HttpClient Module:

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
.
.
.
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpModule,
  HttpClientModule
],
```

Answer (score 6):

Just import the `HttpModule` and the `HttpClientModule` only:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

No need for the `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 5):

In angular github page, this problem was discussed and found solution. 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20355

Comment: I used this link, wleite,s comment in the bottom of the page for this problem in unit & integration tests with Angular 5

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was using a service in a sub module (NOT the root AppModule), and the HttpClientModule was imported only in the module.

So I have to modify the default scope of the service, by changing 'providedIn' to 'any' in the @Injectable decorator.

By default, if you using angular-cli to generate the service, the 'providedIn' was set to 'root'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked for me ..Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case I found once I rebuild the app it worked.

I had imported the `HttpClientModule` as specified in the previous posts but I was still getting the error. I stopped the server, rebuilt the app (`ng serve`) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

My particular issue was that, while I was including `HttpClientModule` correctly in my App Module, where I was injecting a `HttpClient` had imported the "wrong" HttpClient, specifically the HttpClient from a `signalr` package.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@aspnet/signalr';
```

Because I didn't pay attention when the autocomplete was happening,

[image]

I'm have to assume some others have hit a similar issue as well, not that they just haven't imported the HttpClientModule in their App Module.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem for a long time and tried many things and some answers from `stackOverflow`, but for me, there was a missing part of making your project work especially for the new angular version.

first: add `HttpClientModule` to the root app in the file `app.module.ts` in the `import[]` array.
second: add the services to the file `app.module.ts` in the `providers[]`, or inject this service to root application from the service file by using this code inside the service file.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

The last and most important part was for me is to add `importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule)` to the  `providers: []` array in the `app.config.ts` file and import the suitable libraries.

```js
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
  ]
};
```

Comment: This works also without modules, using "standalone" approach.

Comment: Yes, you are right if the developer is using the new version of angular. when generating a project will generate it without a `modules` file that will work, by using the `standalone`. But in this case, don't forget to add the specific modules for each component separately.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the error occured when using a service from an angular module located in an npm package, where the service requires injection of `HttpClient`. When installing the npm package, a duplicate `node_modules` directory was created inside the package directory due to [version conflict handling of npm](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/npm-peer-dependencies-f843f3ac4e7f) (`engi-sdk-client` is the module containing the service):

[image]

Obviously, the dependency to `HttpClient` is not resolved correctly, as the locations of `HttpClientModule` injected into the service (lives in the duplicate `node_modules` directory) and the one injected in `app.module` (the correct `node_modules`) don't match.

I've also had this error in other setups containing a duplicate `node_modules` directory due to a wrong `npm install` call.

This defective setup also leads to the described runtime exception `No provider for HttpClient!`.

> TL;DR; Check for duplicate `node_modules` directories, if none of the
>   other solutions work!

Answer (score 1):

Added

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [...],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

to root module of my-app solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 17 -  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
Go to your app.config.ts
Inside the providers array add:

provideHttpClient()

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideHttpClient(),
  ],
};
```

This fixed my error

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your app.module.ts file.
2. import HttpClientModule file from '@angular/common/http' e.g import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
3. Add HttpClientModule in side the imports:[] e.g imports[HttpClientModule]