# How to configure or pass environment variable to angular library from application module?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

I have an angular library which calls backend java API. I want the ability to configure the API URL in the library through angular application module where I import the library.

I have tried having `forRoot()` in the library but my application gives below runtime error because my application modules are loaded lazily -

> ERROR Error: "StaticInjectorError[FeatureComponent -> Service]: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!"

Below is the code library snippet -

```
 export class LibModule {
      constructor(injector: Injector) {
      setLibInjector(injector);
      }

  public static forRoot(environment: any): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LibModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'appEnv', // use InjectionToken
          useValue: environment
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Below is one of the module in my app where I import the library -

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    LibModule.forChild({baseUrl: '/configuration/'}),
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: []

})
export class FeatureModule {
}
```

**Note**
I want to know how to write a library to accept configuration parameters from any kind of angular module (eagerly or lazily loaded). Someone has marked the question as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No provider for HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236963/no-provider-for-httpclient)

Comment: The question is not duplicate. Please check again @PrashantPimpale

Answer (score 1):

Suppose in your `LibModule` you want to use `environment` in `XyzService`,

**App.module.ts**

```
 imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      LibModule.forRoot({
        environment: environment
      })
   ]
```

**LibModule.module.ts**

```
export class LibModule{ 
  static forRoot(environment): ModuleWithProviders {
    console.log(environment);
    return {
      ngModule: LibModule,
      providers: [XyzService,{provide: 'config', useValue: environment}]
    };
  }
}
```

**XyzService.service :**

```
export class XyzService{

  constructor(@Inject('config') private config:any) {
    console.log(config)
   }
}
```