# I have an error when I use private rest service in constructure, then my html code is not working

Tags: node.js, angular, rest

I have an error when I use private Rest service in constructor, then my HTML code is not working. I want the solution of this error.

```
re.mjs:9171 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[RestService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[RestService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No provider for HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236963/no-provider-for-httpclient)