# Angular 6 - NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient in unit tests

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am importing and using `HttpClient` in a service as follows:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getData() {
        return this.http.get("url...");
    }
}
```

However, when I run `ng test` for my **unit tests**, and when those tests use the service, I am getting the error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
```

The [Angular 6 documentation on HTTP](https://v6.angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#heroes-and-http) just says to do what I did above.

Comment: What is the code of the unit test? It matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4 Error: No provider for HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569404/angular-4-error-no-provider-for-httpclient)

Comment: @KevinDoyon No, my question is about failing in regard to unit tests, not otherwise.

Comment: And that's exactly what that duplicate is about :) You're likely not importing `HttpClientModule` into your test. Your tests create their own modules. If you don't import `HttpClientModule` (or `HttpClientTestingModule`) there, `HttpClient` won't work because Angular doesn't know about it. It doesn't matter that you added `HttpClientModule` to, say, `AppModule`. It needs to be in `TestBed.configureTestingModule`. Could also import a `SharedModule` if you have one, as long as `HttpClientModule` is in the `exports`.But test will be slower because the `SharedModule` would contain unneeded stuff

Comment: @KevinDoyon You're right, thank you, I just needed to import `HttpClientTestingModule`.

Comment: I imported HttpClientTestingModule but it is not working. Still can't find HttpClient...

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { myService } from './myservice';


describe('myService', () => {

      beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule], 
        providers: [myService]
      }));

       it('should be created', () => {
        const service: myService = TestBed.get(myService);
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
       });

       it('should have getData function', () => {
        const service: myService = TestBed.get(myService);
        expect(service.getData).toBeTruthy();
       });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to add `HttpClientTestingModule` to the `imports` array in the `configureTestingModule` method.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to just post that but I said let make it full , am happy it helped

Comment: working for me, I was aspecting to add the module in the main test instead it must be added in the test of the service

Comment: This helped but import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'; is not necessary since the test class does not actually use it.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me in Angular 9.  import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule], 
        providers: [myService]
      }));

Comment: I spent most of my time trying to figure out how to create Jasmine Spy HttpClient object until I found this solution. Thanks.

Comment: A description of what the solution adds--why it works, would be helpful. Without words, I'm forced to do a visual diff between OP's post and this answer.

Comment: In this example, nobody pointed whats the use of HttpTestingController import ?

Comment: I imported HttpClientTestingModule like this but it is not working. Still can't find HttpClient..

Answer (score 1):

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { myService } from './myservice';

describe('HeaderService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
    providers: [myService]
  }));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you should add HttpClient into imports of your module where your component is declared

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**UPDATE:**

`import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';` must tbe included for unit testing

OPs question does not follow unit testing guidelines. HttpClientTestingModule must be imported in beforeEach

```
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule], 
    providers: [dataService]  
  }));
```

Basically, HttpClientTestingModule is injected in dataService for unit testing purposes that prevents StaticInjectorError

Comment: The user asks for unit testing... not using it in a service