# Angular unit testing - injection failing

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying my hand at creating an Angular unit test, but failing right off the bat.

I've taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769401/angular-6-nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-httpclient-in-unit-tests) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769401/angular-6-nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-httpclient-in-unit-tests) this SO, which seems to be exactly what I'm struggling with, but after attempting the fixes mentioned there, I am still not coming right.

This is my code :

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ContactsService } from './contacts.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('ContactsService', () => {


   beforeEach(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule, ContactsService, HttpClient],
  })
  .compileComponents();
  });


});
```

When I run an ng test, I get this error :

> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ContactsService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!

My .ts, for completeness :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Entry } from '../classes/entry';
import { EntrySearch } from '../classes/entrySearch';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

}
```

Comment: This answer on the duplicate target answers perfectly:https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261579/5468463

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import `HttpClientTestingModule` and provide your `ContactsService`:

```
import { ContactsService } from './contacts.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('ContactsService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
    providers: [ ContactsService ]
  }));

 it('should be created', () => {
    const service: ContactsService = TestBed.inject(ContactsService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```

Comment: Using your code, I'm still getting the same error. Am I correct in assuming I don't have to rebuild/restart the ng test?

Comment: You have to run the test again, sue.

Comment: Yep, even after a new ng test, I still get "NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!"

Comment: Did you replace your entire test class with the one I provided above? If not, can you provide a minimal demo?

Comment: Yeah, replaced everything exactly with yours. I've also added my ts to the question now, if it helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is like tilo says, it should have worked.
And also try to make your `beforeEach` - `async()`.

Try this - a little bit modified (see the declarations part):

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ContactsService } from './contacts.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('ContactsService', () => {


   beforeEach(async(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       declarations: [ContactsService],
       imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule]
  })
  .compileComponents();
  }));


});
```